# Saving a image to server after http post - android to php

Tags: php, android, image, file, post

Struggled with this for a few hours now so time to ask a question.

Im sending a multipart http post from android to php server using apachehttpclient jar package.

Once the info is posted to php im trying to save the image to a folder so I can work with it:

```
<?php

require("fpdf.php");

//Receive the data from android
$name = $_POST['email'];
$data = $_POST['data'];

//Receive the file
$file = $_FILES['image'];

//$newpath = "/";
//file_put_contents($newpath, $file);

if(move_uploaded_file($file, $newpath)) {

echo json_encode(
        array(
            'result'=>$data,
            'msg'=>'Report added successfully.'
            )
        );
}else {
//something else 
};

?>
```

I have tried `move_upload_file` *as above* and also `file_put_contents($newpath, $file);`

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this mock-up code or the exact code you're working with? If it's the latter, you've commented out the closing parentheses on the conditional statement at the bottom. It seems too trivial to be the problem, however, so feel free to ignore me if I'm looking at things wrongly.

Comment: apologies. yes this is just mock up code. i have fixed this in the edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the php script i use for uploading photos to server from ios applications.

```
<?php
$uploadDir = './images/';      //Uploading to directory specified
$file = basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
$uploadFile = $file;
$randomNumber = rand(0, 99999999999); 
$newName = $uploadDir . $randomNumber . $uploadFile;


if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'])) {
    echo "Temp file uploaded. \r\n";
} else {
    echo "Temp file not uploaded. \r\n";
}

if ($_FILES['userfile']['size']> 100000000) {
    exit("Your file is too large."); 
}

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $newName)) {
    $maxsize = ini_get('upload_max_filesize');
    echo "http://www.mydomain.com/images/{$file}" . "\r\n" . $_FILES['userfile']['size'] . "\r\n" . $_FILES['userfile']['type'] ;
    echo $randomNumber;
}
?>
```